# Locus of centre of circle in Lambert theorem

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

A beautiful theorem, when three tangents to a parabola form a triangle,the focus of the parabola lies on the circumcircle of the triangle. But what is the locus of the centre of the circumcircle of the triangle? Using web or library resources I haven't  been able to find a relevant link or page and the demonstration (which I don't ask for) is too challenging for me.

Comment: If I've done my algebra correctly, the circumcenter $P(h,k)$ of the triangle determined by tangents to points $A(a,a^2)$, $B(b,b^2)$, $C(c,c^2)$ of the parabola $y = x^2$ is given by $$h = \frac{1}{4}\left(a+b+c-4 a b c\right)\qquad k = \frac{1}{8}\left(1 + 4 a b + 4 b c + 4 c a \right)$$ Holding any two of $A$, $B$, $C$ fixed, and allowing the other to vary, causes $P$ to trace a line. I don't know if the line has any particular geometric significance. (The line is not necessarily parallel to the fixed points of tangency, for instance.) Is this the kind of thing you're after?

Comment: Correct if two points are fixed it is indeed a line. However I wonder if there is an expression for that locus containing the parabola parameter (p) and independant on any number of points being fixed. (of course the triangle must exist) I do not know if this is possible, it is not a homework, it is just for curiosity's sake.

Comment: There is perhaps an analogy with locus of the center of an equilateral triangle circumscribing a given parabola (ie sides are tangents to the parabola) - which is the directrix.[See here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CenterOfAnEquilateralTriangleCircumscribingAGivenParabola/). In Lambert's Theorem the triangle needs not to be equilateral

Comment: When you allow all the points to vary independently, you get a continuous family of lines. (You don't get *every possible* line, however.) Are you expecting/hoping that they cover (or leave uncovered) a particularly-nice portion of the plane?

Comment: Yes,I expect only a portion of the plane to be covered.